# The 'if' statement is not running

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

When I run this code, for some strange reason, the if statement is never run, so the console simply returns nothing. However, the code is unfinished (as you can probably see by the fact there are 3 other options not completed), but I wrote the code so that I could copy and paste this for the others. I tried to add some `print('test')` to try and locate the problem; and have found it starts at the `if` statement of `if skill == 'dexterity'`. If anyone could help that would be great, as I don't know if this is a bug in my computer or just me being silly. This has happened before on this computer though, and it was never resolved.
Edit: I have changed the .lower to .lower() and the while statement, but still to no avail.
Edit 2: My IDLE was bugged, and thus the problem has been solved :D.

```
def charac_create():
player_skill = {
    'dexterity' : 0,
    'strength' : 0,
    'wisdom' : 0,
    'health' : 0
}
point_pool = 30
player_choice = input('Hello, and welcome to the skill tree!' \
                      ' What skill would you like to change:' \
                      ' Dexterity, Strength, Wisdom or Health?' \
                      ' You only have 30 points, so spend wisely!' \
                      ' If you want to exit, simply type "nope"!')
skill = player_choice.lower()
if skill == 'dexterity':
    print('test')
    return 'test'
    choice = input('Ahh, sleight of hand! A good choice.' \
                   'How would you like to change it?(+ or -)')
    while choice != '+' or choice != '-':
        print('That\'s not what I asked!')
        choice = input('How would you like to change it?(+ or -)')
    if choice == '+':
        n = int(input('By how much?'))
        if n < 0:
            print('This is a positive number, not negative!')
            n = int(input('By how much?'))
        elif n > 0:
            if n > pointpool:
                print('You don\'t have enough points!')
                n = int(input('By how much?'))
            elif n < pointpool: 
                pointpool -= n
                player_skill['dexterity'] += n
                print('Your dexterity is now ' + player_skill['dexterity'] + 'points,' \
                      'and you have ' + pointpool + ' points left!')
    elif choice == '-':
        n = int(input('By how much?'))
        if n > 0:
            print('This is a negative number, not positive!')
            n = int(input('By how much?'))
        elif n < 0:
            if player_skill['dexterity'] - n > 0:
                print('You can\'t take out more points than there are!')
                n = int(input('By how much?'))
            elif player_skill['dexterity'] - n < 0: 
                pointpool += n
                player_skill['dexterity'] -= n
                print('Your dexterity is now ' + player_skill['dexterity'] + 'points,' \
                      'and you have ' + pointpool + ' points left!')
else:
    print('test')
    return 'test'
charac_create()
```

Comment: `skill = player_choice.lower`

Comment: You got some dead code, code after return 'test' will not execute.

Comment: @Beri I assume they were just doing that for testing purposes to see if they ever hit it, and to short-circuit if so (I could be wrong though, you know what happens when you assume...)

Comment: As a side note, you don't need (and shouldn't use) backslash continuations when you're inside parentheses, as in your long `input` statements. Also, it's often helpful to assign long text like that to a variable outside the function call, so you can fit an extra ~20 characters/line.

Comment: After your edit, `while choice != '+' or choice != '-'` is always true; any value at all is either not `+` or not `-`, including `+` and `-`.

Comment: Also, more importantly, when you get an answer to your problem, don't edit your question to incorporate that answer and ask a new question. It makes the answers incorrect and useless, even though the person who went through the trouble of writing them actually helped you, and even though their answers would otherwise help other people with the same problem as you in the future. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: One last thing: Instead of vague descriptions like "I tried to add some print('test') to try and locate the problem; and have found it starts at the if statement", show us the code with those `print('test')` calls left in, and show us the exact output you get.

Comment: thanks, I will try to improve my syntax next time I post a question. :)

Answer (score 3):

This line assigns the *function* `lower` to the variable `skill`

```
skill = player_choice.lower
```

You need to call the function to assign the return value to the variable

```
skill = player_choice.lower()
```

See the following example

```
s = 'test'

>>> s.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x01EC0960>  # this is the function

>>> s.lower()
'test'     # this is the returned value
```

Comment: I'm afraid still nothing, even after .lower(). Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and everything seems to work fine. The code under if statement is getting executed, although I had to use raw_input instead of input to make it work. Also I had to remove the return after print, which I guess you put there for testing

Comment: Thanks, I think my IDLE is bugged. :P

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled the python IDLE on to 3.4.2 and have managed to get it working again; must have been a bugged IDLE or my computer. Thanks for everyone who helped me with this problem too; you solved quite a few syntax errors! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use and `while choice != '+' and choice !='-'` instead of or to make your logic work.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it by making a list (`answers = ['+','-']`) and using `while choice not in answers`.